# XPATH - how to get all text() elements of any node type having a particular attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <div lang="en">Everyday Italian</div>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price dollarValue="1.5">30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price dollarValue="1.5">29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price dollarValue="1.5">49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <p lang="en">Learning XML</p>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price dollarValue="1.5">39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

In the above XML data

I'd like to get the text() nodes which have an attribute of `lang="en"`

So this would mean matching

```
<div lang="en">data</div>
<title lang="en">data</title>
<p lang="en">data</p>
```

The nodes are not restricted to `title,div,p` there might be many more. so i can't query these seperately

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*` to reference element nodes of any name, for example :

```
//*[@lang='en']/text()
```